# How can I turn off anti-aliasing for one specific JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, antialiasing

How can I turn off anti-aliasing for one specific JLabel? It uses a very small font which might look better without anti-aliasing.

If important, I'm using Java 1.5 on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to override the paint(Graphics g) method and draw the text yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried overriding paint(Graphics g) or paintComponent(Graphics g), setting rendering hints for text AA on the graphics object and calling the super method?

see RenderingHints:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_OFF